# D2007 bug when define record directly as class field

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

When you define a `record` directly as a class field:

```
TTest = class
private
  fData: record
    I: Integer;
    X: Real
  end;
  procedure NavigationDontWorkHere();
protected
  procedure A();
public
  function B(): Integer;
end;
```

Navigation (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Up</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Down</kbd>) is broken for `NavigationDontWorkHere` method, and class auto-completion (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd>) works but adds a second definition of `NavigationDontWorkHere` method.

Moving the `record` definition to the end of the class:

```
TTest = class
protected
  procedure A();
public
  function B(): Integer;
private
  fData: record
    I: Integer;
    X: Real
  end;
end;
```

Fixes navigation but completely breaks class auto-completion.

The only way I have found to fix it is to declare the `record` before the class:

```
TTestData = record
  I: Integer;
  X: Real
end;

TTest = class
private
  fData: TTestData;
protected
  procedure A();
public
  function B(): Integer;
end;
```

Does anyone know a way to define the `record` directly in the class and keep normal IDE functionality working correctly?

Is it a bug fixed in more recent Delphi versions?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no workaround for this problem in old versions of Delphi. It is fixed in modern versions.

Comment: I haven't found a workaround either.  It is possible that REGIONS might work, but I haven't tried them because I hate them.